# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in the web application

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, exception, garbage-collection

I have an web application that continuously sends 3 ajax requests every second. These ajax request are made to 3 different servlets. To begin with my application runs fine but after some time it throws`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception.
I couldn't figure out the reason of this exception. I am declaring some collections in my server side java code.Is it the memory these variables keep on consuming in the heap?

Comment: that sounds the most likely.

Comment: no idea, you didn't show any (reduced) code? run your code, keep a process monitor open, see if the memory footprint goes up steadily as you use it, and stays stable if you don't make it do ajax calls. If that's the case: time for you to start going through your code and looking at where you're using Vector/ArrayList/etc when you really should be using fixed length containers to prevent infinite data accumulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` JVM argument then open the Heap Dump in MAT.

MAT will show you the suspects of the OOM, you can even walk through the heap yourself and identify which objects occupy the most of the heap. This way you can easily find the culprit of the problem.

Comment: You can also use VisualVM - which is shipped with the oracle JDK. http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html   Though MAT is also a great tool for heap dumps.

Comment: Can i do this in Eclipse IDE??

Comment: Yes, you can modify the startup VM arguments of the app that you are launching from your IDE. That will make the HeapDump to be collected. Then you can open it in MAT.

Answer (score 1):

Do you store your collections in Servlet class fields or inside method processRequest?

Servlets are "kind of" Singleton there is only one object of every servlet class in your web container so if you still add objects to this collections you obviously will get OutOfMemory

You can clear your collections from time to time or manage objects which are inside these collections